# Open Project from SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

My primary dev workstation has tortise and visualSVN installed and VS10 offers me a command off my File menu - 'Open Solution from SVN' - (or something to that effect...I can't open that workstation right now so the wording is probably different. But the point is that i has a way to open a project that stored at my VisualSVN server and all files are copied down to my workstation with source control active. I can 'update to latest' and make my commits.

I'm trying to get to that same level of functionality on a new workstation - have both tortise and visualSVN installed...and within VS10 i have the VisualSVN menu and tortiese context menu items. But I'm not seeing the 'Open from SVN' at the file menu and don't see how I'm supposed to import the project from the VisualSVN server.

.
.
NOTE: I was just able to reboot that server (hope springs eternal) and verify the menu struture...On Visual Studio's main File menu - at the top - is "Open" where the only item is a flyout menu - the only item on *that* is 'Open From SVN'. This is what's missing on the new workstation's visual studio implmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do a SVN Checkout using Tortoise and open the solution file in VS?

Comment: i suppose so ... but i'd also like to understand why/how my tools work or don't - especially when it comes to version control. Here's a situation where I have identical versions of the same toolset and they act differently.

Comment: I've just stepped thru this suggestion - Tortoise SVN checkout and then opening in VS. But the solution isn't opened with Source Control enabled...and any attempts to add the solution to SC give me a dialog to Team Foundation Server and no other alternative sc. Perhaps the visual svn install is hosed?